# Extract positive and negative words from text?

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk, pos-tagger, senti-wordnet

I need to find the opinion of certain reviews given in websites. I am using sentiwordnet for this. I first send the file containing all the reviews to POS Tagger.

Is there any other accurate way of tokenizing which considers not good as 1 word other than considering it as 2 separate words.

Now I have to give postive and negative score to the tokenized words and then calculate the total score. Is there any function in sentiwordnet for this. please help.

```
import nltk
from not.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
import CSV

para = "What can I say about this place. The staff of the restaurant is nice and the eggplant is not bad. Apart from that, very uninspired food, lack of atmosphere and too expensive. I am a staunch vegetarian and was sorely disappointed with the veggie options on the menu. Will be the last time I visit, I recommend others to avoid"

sentense = word_tokenize(para)
word_features = []

for i,j in nltk.pos_tag(sentense):
    if j in ['JJ', 'JJR', 'JJS', 'RB', 'RBR', 'RBS']:
        word_features.append(i)

rating = 0

for i in word_features:
    with open('words.txt', 'rt') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            if i == row[0]:
                print i, row[1]
                if row[1] == 'pos':
                    rating = rating + 1
                elif row[1] == 'neg':
                    rating = rating - 1
print  rating
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Emotional from text/pORnOfWord.py", line 10, in <module>
    for i,j in nltk.pos_tag(sentense):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\__init__.py", line 99, in pos_tag
    tagger = load(_POS_TAGGER)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 605, in load
    resource_val = pickle.load(_open(resource_url))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 686, in _open
    return find(path).open()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 467, in find
    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError:
**********************************************************************
  Resource 'taggers/maxent_treebank_pos_tagger/english.pickle' not
  found.  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:
  >>> nltk.download()
  Searched in:
    - `enter code here`'C:\\Users\\Eman\x99/nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\\nltk_data'
    - 'E:\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Python27\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\Eman\x99\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data'
```

Comment: You need to install the `pos_tag` NLTK submodule. `nltk.download('maxent_treebank_pos_tagger')`

Comment: `nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')`

Answer (score 0):

The error has occurred due to missing nltk packages, which will be resolved by downloading the package, execute the below code to resolve the issue

```
import nltk 
nltk.download()
```